# Incompatible types in assignment error in c

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I am writing a game and currently working on an undo move. This should be very simple but I am getting this error and cant seem to figure it out. 
Here is my function...

```
bb_undo(BBoard board){
board->score = board->previousScore;
board->boardDim = board->previousBoard;
}
```

And here is the board structure...

```
struct bboard {
char boardDim[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
int score;
int rows;
int cols;
char previousBoard[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
int previousScore;
};
```

I should also probably add that bboard is a pointer.
Anybody have any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Have a struct to represent a move. Your game state should contain a stack of these moves, and a function to apply and undo a move. The move struct should have enough info in order to be undone. Now, instead of keeping whole copies of previous board states around, you can just apply the undo of a move from the top of the stack and pop it.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays have no the assignmnet operator. So instead of this statement

```
board->boardDim = board->previousBoard;
```

you have to copy arrays for example with using `memcpy`

Answer (score 3):

Arrays can't be assigned to.

You'll need to either uses `memcpy`, or, since structs *can* be assigned to, you can define

```
struct board 
{
    char cells[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
};
```

and change `bboard`

```
struct bboard {
    board boardDim;
    int score;
    int rows;
    int cols;
    board previousBoard;
    int previousScore;
};
```

and then you can write

```
bboard b;
b.previousBoard = b.boardDim;
```

but you'll need

```
b.previousBoard.cells[x][y];
```

to access the elements.

Of course, you can add accessor functions to `board` to get rid of that annoyance:

```
struct board 
{
    char  operator() (size_t r, size_t c) const { return cells[r][c]; }
    char& operator() (size_t r, size_t c)       { return cells[r][c]; }
    char cells[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
};
```

so you can write

```
char value = b.previousBoard(x, y);
```

and

```
b.previousBoard(x, y) = 'x';
```